# Leveling post level 70

Tags: ps3, dungeon-defenders

Dungeon Defenders for PS3 finally got updates fixing many bugs and raising the level cap.
However the amount of experience required just to go up a single level past level 70 is more than all previous experience earned combined!

Are there now faster ways to earn experience?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way is to run glitterhelm caverns on insane(with hardcore on if the ps3 version has this) repeatedly. Once you've got a build down, you'll be netting about 2.4-3 mil xp per run.

I would also highly recommend purchasing the XP boost from the tavern keep each time you level up, as this can shave a bit of time off.